# Most python way to write from GCS to Postgresql in airflow

Tags: python, postgresql, airflow

I am building an airflow dag that takes csv files from GCS and inserts them to a postgresql table in cloud SQL. I have several options:

- Use sqlalchemy to insert the reows.
- Use pandas
- Explore PostgreSQL airflow operators (I don't know how to connect them with gcs).

Which is the most pythonic way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You sould go with COPY.

See  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html

COPY moves data between PostgreSQL tables and standard file-system files. COPY TO copies the contents of a table to a file, while COPY FROM copies data from a file to a table (appending the data to whatever is in the table already).